# How do I make a UIViewController the delegate for a separate UITableViewController?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4

I have a UITabBarController which has on one of its tabs, a UINavigationController.  The UINavigationController then has a custom UIViewController as its main view.

Based on an IBAction triggered by a button in the custom UIViewController I'm pushing a UITableView controller onto the UINavigationController stack like so. (Note: these are only snippets of the actual code).

Header file for main UIViewController:

```
@interface ATMs : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate> {
}
- (IBAction) showLocationList;
@end
```

Implementation file for main UIViewController:

```
@implementation ATMs
- (void)showLocationList {

    LocationList *locationTableController = [[LocationList alloc] initWithNibName:@"LocationList" bundle:nil];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:locationTableController animated:YES];
    [locationTableController release];

}
```

The `locationTableController` view controller does a fetch to Core Data for a list of objects and displays them on the table.  When a user selects a row, I want the following things to happen:

- pop the `locationTableController` off the navigation controller so that my `ATMs` view controller is visible
- call a method in `ATMs`, passing in the object represented by the row tapped in `locationTableController`

I tried to do this by using the `[locationTableController setDelegate:self];` in `showLocationList` just beneath where I `alloc` the UITableViewController and adding the `UITableViewDelegate` to the header for `ATMs`.
But when I do the above, I get a build error saying that `locationTableController` may not respond to `setDelegate`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In simple terms and without examining the rest of your code, you need to instantiate the UITableViewController and set its tableView (not the TableViewController) delegate as self.

Then you can implement `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` in your ATM UIViewController and it will be called once a row is selected in your tableView.

I'd also present your tableViewController modally as per code below, and declare it as an instance variable so you can dismiss it when the tableview delegate method is called:

```
@class LocationList
@interface ATMs : UIViewController
{
   LocationList *locationTableController
   ...
}
```

And in your implementation:

```
@implementation ATMs
...
- (void)showLocationList 
{
    locationTableController = [[LocationList alloc] initWithNibName:@"LocationList" bundle:nil];
    locationTableController.tableView.delegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:locationTableContrller animated:YES];
    [locationTableController release];
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [locationTableController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    // Rest of your implementation code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by various approaches like : -

1. Delegation pattern
2. Notifications
3. By using class methods (getter/setters), in ATM controller, on in some other manager class
4. Key Value Observations.

but I think the best approach would be to create your own delegate method, and send the callback when row gets selected in LocationList, along with the data you want on ATM controller

Comment: the error shows up as you are using `locationTableController setDelegate:self];` , but you have not defined any `delegate' accessor (getter/setter) in LocationList. This is the reason, it is not able to find any setter for Delegate. If you want to use this approach, then try to create a property with name `delegate`, in locationList tableController

Comment: That is not entirely correct. The OP needed to set self as the delegate for the tableView instead of the tableViewController.

Comment: @Rog Yes, I have just noticed that. It should be tableView.delegate, instead of tableViewController.delegate. Thanks for pointing